# How to add DocumentBlockExtension in uima ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

When I try to use DocumentBlock it shows not define in script block. How I need to add it in additional Engine? Can anyone explain in detail about the usage of DocumentBlock.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you call/execute the RutaEngine. You need to add `org.apache.uima.ruta.block.DocumentBlockExtension` to the value of the configuration parameter `additionalExtensions`.

Using uimaFIT, this would look like:

```
AnalysisEngineFactory.createEngineDescription(RutaEngine.class, ..., 
    RutaEngine.PARAM_ADDITIONAL_EXTENSIONS, new String[] { 
    DocumentBlockExtension.class.getName() });
```

In a simple Ruta project, the value needs to be set in `descriptor/BasicEngine.xml` which is used as a template for the generated descriptors which are used in the launch configuration, if it is not automatically set in the generated descriptor.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: even after adding org.apache.uima.ruta.block.DocumentBlockExtension in   configuration parameter under additionalExtensions. It showing not define in script block.

Comment: The editor uses a different extension for syntax checks which was missing in previous releases. Have you tried to run the analysis engine anyway?

Comment: yeah.I tried to run.But it shows error message..One more thing.After each execution DocumentBlockExtension is getting removed from AE. Whether there is any way to fix it.

Comment: Is it a simple ruta project? Then, you have to add it in BasicEngine.xml. The others descriptors will be overidden.

Comment: Now I'm not receiving the error message. Can you explain in detail about the usage of DocumentBlock.

Comment: I extended to answer, but I am not sure what you want to know about the usage beyond the documentation.

Comment: I'm not clear with the example given in the documentation.